# Accessing SVN Repository on CIFS (Samba) share

Tags: svn

I've installed SVN on my Raspberry PI and configured it to access the repository on a network drive.

In `/etc/fstab` I have the following:

```
//192.168.1.12/SHARE/repos /media/repos cifs sec=ntlm,username=Guest,password=,_netdev,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777 0 0
```

This mounts with no issues.

When I go to add a project to the repository using the following command:

```
sudo svn import mywebsite/ file://media/repos/mainrepository/mywebsite/ -m "Initial Upload"
```

I get the following error:

```
svn: E170000: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file://media/repos/mainrepository/mywebsite'
svn: E170000: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E170000: Local URL 'file://media/repos/mainrepository/mywebsite' contains unsupported hostname
```

The only thing I think maybe causing the issue is the file settings:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    0 Jun 11  2009 repos
```

As you can see the owner is **root**.
I think it needs to be **www-data**, but for some reason I can't change it.

Comment: If the ownership really bothers you, the **cifs** filesystem has 2 options related to security: `uid` and `gid`. So you could try mounting the share with `uid=www-data,gid=www-data,dir_mode=0775,file_mode=0775` (if it fails, use their numerical IDs).

Answer (score 4):

Your local file URL is wrong and actually refers to `media` either as a relative path name or as a hostname, which obviously isn't supported.

Try either of the following URLs:

```
file:///media/repos/mainrepository/mywebsite/

file://localhost/media/repos/mainrepository/mywebsite/
```

Note the third slash in the first example.

Try to read the actual protocol identifier on your own. Similar to `http://` there are two slashes, so `file://media/...` becomes `media/...` rather than `/media/...`.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I tried that and now I'm getting a different error: svn: E000005: Can't move '/media/repos/mainrepository/db/svn-siUlpa' to '/media/repos/mainrepository/db/txn-current': Input/output error

Comment: I suspect this may be down to the permissions on the repository.

Comment: file permissions solved, but still getting the same error.

Comment: You should edit/update your initial question so people immediately see the current issue. Are you really sure the permissions are correct now? Even for the (typically hidden) **.svn** directory?